# How can I write a sandbox for iOS in purpose of check ing vulnerabilities?

Tags: iphone, security, sandbox, mobile-application

I need to write a sandbox for iOS. The goal is to monitor malicious app. It need to have the capability of moving apps on my iPhone into my sandbox and monitor malicious app if there is.

I only need that as a simulation meaning I’ll write two apps one malicious and one safe and while trying to move them into my sandbox I need to send some info about the apps to my back-end that checks for vulnerability.

I only care about understanding how to create this sand box and have this communication with those two apps. Any idea from where should I start?